# How are unique registration id's for GCM for each device generated?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have to test my app for `GCM` multicast on emulators around 10 or more in number. For this I need to create 10 emulators that can provide me unique registration ids.

I tried cloning a single emulator with a **google account** and loading the userdata-qemu.img into new emulator. In this case the registration ids returned by the new emulator is same as the old one.

I tested the app on two separately created emulators with the same google account in which case they 
return different registration ids. Certainly `GCM` does not use account information for that.

I understand that registration id for `GCM` is generated from the "**app package and device**".
How does Google uniquely identify a device or emulator instance.

Also tried changing the uuid of the emulator provided in the emulator-user.ini file but of no use.

Certainly I can go about doing this manually , but it would be too cumbersome each time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK the device manufacturer sets the unique id. You can use UUID.randomUUID() for your tests store it and test.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. YEs, the device uuid would be unique and cannot be changed. But on emulators it should be possible to set it. I am not sure if it is stored as SharedPreferences in GCM. I would try this and get back. Thanks.

Comment: No i'm not talking about the device's UUID but to generate one for each device

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got it. Actually, I need this for testing the multicast function of GCM and not for tracking individual installations of my app on each device. So, generating random UUID would solve the issue if Google is using it to generate registration id otherwise back to square one. However, worth trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

The exact algorithm of ID generation is an implementation detail - it's not disclosed, Google is free to change it anytime, and relying on it would be unwise.